# Identify date timestamps where time is missing

Tags: ms-access, timestamp

I have an error in my original data taken from a weather station recording every five minutes where by the timestamps at midnight only consist of the date but not the time i.e following an entry of `06/03/2018 23:55:00` I have `06/03/2018` but with no attached `00:00:00`. The sequence runs over multiples years so and for every midnight entry there is just a date with no time. How can I select these entries out and run an update query to amend the time `00:00:00` to them?

Many thanks,

Matt

***sample data:***

[image]

Comment: You don't. Date/time is actually stored as a double number. Decimal part of a number never stores 0. Midnight has 0 time part therefore midnight date/time never shows time portion. The date/time structure you see is a default format display of double number.

Comment: @Gustav Thank you once again. There is however no tick option to mark this as answered yet?

Comment: I moved the comment to an answer ...

Answer (score 0):

Apply the format to the Time field:

```
dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss
```

where you wish to display the values.